# How to create Nested menus on Vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, menu, nested, vuetify.js

I'm currently usinfg Vuetify 1.5.18 and having some issues trying to create a nested menu usint the `toolbar` component and `list-group`.

The menu is working but when I click to expand it closes.

Here's the CodePen: https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/dybBmKj

And here the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
        <v-menu open-on-hover bottom offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-on="on"
          >
            Dropdown
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-list>
            <v-list-group
              v-for="item in items"
              :key="item.title"
              v-model="item.active"
              :prepend-icon="item.action"
              no-action
            >
              <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-list-tile>
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
              </template>

              <v-list-tile
                v-for="subItem in item.items"
                :key="subItem.title"
                @click=""
              >
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>

                <v-list-tile-action>
                  <v-icon>{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-tile-action>
              </v-list-tile>
            </v-list-group>
          </v-list>
      </v-menu>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
        {
          action: 'local_activity',
          title: 'Attractions',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'restaurant',
          title: 'Dining',
          active: true,
          items: [
            { title: 'Breakfast & brunch' },
            { title: 'New American' },
            { title: 'Sushi' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'school',
          title: 'Education',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'directions_run',
          title: 'Family',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'healing',
          title: 'Health',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'content_cut',
          title: 'Office',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: 'local_offer',
          title: 'Promotions',
          items: [
            { title: 'List Item' }
          ]
        }
      ]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. Working adding `:close-on-content-click="false"` on the `v-menu`:

```
 <v-menu
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-width="200"
        offset-x
      >
```

Codepen updated: https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/dybBmKj

Comment: Word of caution: as the option name implies, this prevents the menu from closing when an option is selected, which might be undesirable. The answer from @mithun-das is more flexible and I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this thing in v-list-group as  (:close-on-content-click="true") by default in my case I solved it by this adding (@click.stop).

```
 <v-list-group
   @click.stop
   v-for="item in items"
   :key="item.title"
   v-model="item.active"
   :prepend-icon="item.action"
   no-action
 >
```