# Vuetify v-menu open a submenu

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to divide this menu into submenu I cannot divide these items below
This menu I will call router as functions
I searched on google and I didn't understand how I do this for with the sub-menu

```html
<div id="v-menu">
          <v-menu offset-y>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn outlined color="blue" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                <v-icon left small>mdi-cogs</v-icon> Mais Ações<v-icon
                  color="black"
                  right
                  medium
                  >mdi-chevron-down</v-icon
                >
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, index) in itemsmenuRel"
                :key="index"
                router
                :to="item.link"
                style="max-height: 0px"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>
                  <v-icon left small>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon
                  >{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title
                >
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
 </div>
```

This is an example of an array

```js
itemsmenuRel: [
      {
        title: "Menu1",
        icon: "mdi-file-cog-outline",
        subLinks: [
          { text: "Add Manager1", route: "/managers/add" },
          { text: "Managers2", route: "/managers" },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "Menu2",
        icon: "mdi-image-filter-drama",
        subLinks: [
          { text: "Add Manager3", route: "/managers/add" },
          { text: "Managers4", route: "/managers" },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

Comment: A simple search founds this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178206/how-to-create-nested-menus-on-vuetify