# Creating a nested mennu on vuetify

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a nested menu for my vuetify projeect based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178206/how-to-create-nested-menus-on-vuetify) example.
My code looks like this:

```
<template>
<v-container>
    <v-app>
        <v-app-bar app>
            <v-toolbar-title>Schnitzeljagd</v-toolbar-title>
            <!-- OLD CODE -->
            <v-menu :close-on-content-click="false" open-on-hover bottom offset-y>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn icon v-on="on">
                        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>

                <v-list>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-list>
                            <select v-model="locale">
                                <option v-for="lang in locales" :key="lang.code" :value="lang.code">{{
                                        lang.name
                                }}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </v-list>
                    </v-list-item>

                    <v-list-group v-model="active" no-action>
                        <template v-slot:activator>
                            <v-list-tile>
                                <v-list-tile-content>
                                    <v-list-tile-title>Language</v-list-tile-title>
                                </v-list-tile-content>
                            </v-list-tile>
                        </template>
                        <select>
                            <option v-for="lang in locales" :key="lang.code">
                                   {{ lang.name }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
            <!-- NEW CODE -->


                    </v-list-group>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
            <v-menu left bottom>


                <v-list>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <LanguageSwitcher />
                    </v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-list color="deep-purple accent-4" dense dark>
                            <select v-model="locale">
                                <option v-for="lang in locales" :key="lang.code" :value="lang.code">{{
                                        lang.name
                                }}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </v-list>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
        </v-app-bar>

    </v-app>
</v-container>
```

```
<script>

export default {

    data: () => ({
      locales: [
            { name: 'English' },
            { title: 'Italian' },
          ]
    }),
    components: {}
}
</script>
```

As you can see I have commented two blocks of code, once as "old code" and once as "new code". Since the menu I get from the old code does not look good I want to adjust it and get a new version (new code) which is looking like the example linked previously.

But somehow I cannot get the items in the list to be clickable.

Comment: please show the code for the `LanguageSwitcher` component

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

1. You are setting `v-model` to the `locale` variable, but you do not have it defined in `data`.
2. The `locales` array of objects is not uniform and the objects are missing the `code` property.

Fixes:

1. `data` should have the `locale` defined:

```js
data: () => ({
  locale: null
})
```

2. The `locales` array should be uniform and w/out missing data:

```js
locales: [
  {
    name: 'English', // or title, pick one
    code: 'en' // I'm assuming ISO here
  },
  {
    name: 'Italian',
    code: 'it'
  }
]
```

As for the layout, this is a menu using `vuetify 2`:

```html
<v-menu left bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn icon v-on="on">
      <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>

  <v-list>
    <v-list-item-group v-model="locale">
      <v-list-item v-for="lang in locales" :key="lang.code" :value="lang.code">
        {{ lang.name }}
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  <v-list>
</v-menu>
```

If you want for "something" to happen when user selects the language name, you can `watch` for changes on the `locale`.

More `v-list` [examples](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#examples).